# Wordpress/CMS for small business SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, cms

It's oft-heard that Wordpress has top-notch SEO and there are even rumors that Google's algorithms (and other search engines) are designed to specifically favor Wordpress-based sites.

If I'm in charge of boosting SEO for a small service business website whose only relevant customer base is in its municipality, should I remake the whole site (presently hand-coded) in Wordpress or some CMS?

Do Google and others really favor CMS-based sites when evaluating local business search queries?

Comment: The reference to the "This question already has an answer" probably should point to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/why-does-seo-seem-to-hinge-on-using-wordpress instead of the current suggestion.

Comment: Good point, by the way I preferred your first comment before you edited.. ;)

Comment: Also worth checking out: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use for pointers on selecting a CMS.

Comment: @bybe Yeah, well.  Discretion is the better part of valor now :p